# Problem on finding limit of sequence $u_{n+1}=a-u_n^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've a small problem when I try to find the limit of this sequence:
$u_0=0, u_{n+1}=a-u_n^2=f(u_n)$ with $a\leq \dfrac{3}{4}$. I've shown that :

- $u_{n+1}\leq a$ and $u_{n+1}\geq a-a^2\geq 0\Rightarrow 0<u_n<a$ $\forall a>1$
- $f'(x)=-2x<0$ $\forall x>0$, otherwise $0=u_0<u_2$, so $\{u_{2n}\}$ is a increase sequence and $\{u_{2n+1}\}$ is a decrease sequence
- so $\lim u_{2n}=A$, and $\lim u_{2n+1}=B$ $(0\leq A,B\leq a$), but how can I prove that $A=B$ ?

Comment: If $u$ is the limit, it must satisfy $u=a-u^2$

Comment: Note that $2$-cycles exist if $f(f(x))=x$ has at least two distinct roots (and even three, but forget it), where $f(x)=a-x^2$. Now, $f(f(x))=x$ means $g(x)=0$ with $g(x)=x^4-2ax^2+x+a^2-a$. The sign of $g''(x)=4(3x^2-a)$ is clear and the condition $a\leqslant\frac34$ guarantees exactly that $g'(x)\geqslant0$ at the point where $g''(x)=0$, that is, where $g'$ is minimal. Thus, $g'\geqslant0$ on $(0,a)$ hence $g$ has at most one root. Snce $A=f(B)$ and $B=f(A)$, this proves that $A=B$, qed.

Comment: are you sure it converges?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your calculations are correct (otherwise the rest does not hold), then necessarily $0< A,B< a$ and because $a<1$ you also know that $$0< A^2,B^2< a \tag{*}$$ Then for $n\in \mathbb N$ you have that $$u_{2n}^{\phantom{1}}=a-u^2_{2n-1}=a-(a-u^2_{2(n-1)})^2$$ and taking the limit $$A=a-(a-A^2)^2\tag1$$ In the same way you get $$B=a-(a-B^2)^2\tag2$$ Now, assume that $B\neq A$ and take $(2)-(1)$ to get a contradiction:

\begin{align}B-A&=(a-A^2)^2-(a-B^2)^2=(B-A)(B+A)(2a-A^2-B^2) \\[0.3cm] \iff \hspace{20pt} 0&=(B+A)(2a-A^2-B^2)\\[0.3cm]\iff \hspace{20pt}  0 &=A+B \quad\text{ or }\\[0.3cm]0&=(a-A^2)+(a-B^2)\end{align}

a contradiction since by $(^*)$ both $A^2,B^2$ are less than $a$ and greater than $0$.